# How to get sum of values in two tables per day

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables in my database *AllSellerDetails* and *IncomeDetails*. The number of records in these two tables are different. i need to display sum of all the fields of these two tables in one query
Here is my code

```
select 
    ASD.date as Date, 
    sum(ASD.saleAmt) as Sale, 
    sum(ASD.totalBillAmt) as BillAmt, 
    sum(ASD.loss) as Loss, sum(ASD.excess) as Excess, 
    sum(ASD.comm+ASD.boxexp+ASD.marketexp+ASD.otherExp) as comm, 
    (select sum(amount) from incomeDetails I where ASD.date = I.date) as Income, 
    (select sum(amount) from expenceDetails E where ASD.date = E.date) as Expence 
 from AllsellerDetails ASD 
 group by date;
```

This code gives the data related to the first table

Comment: This code doesn't perform *any* kind of join. Are you confusing subqueries for joins? In any case, joining means returning related rows, *not* aggregating them

Comment: sorry dude...i need datas of both table. what should i do